# Is a gravitational singularity distinct from a topological hole?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, singularity, general-relativity

In the context of a spacetime (e.g., definition 1 [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005V2ZYWG)) of classical general relativity theory, what is the technical mathematical difference(s) between a [gravitational singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity) and a topological hole? The two seem similar, naively, in the sense that neither are considered to be "part" of the manifold, and that one cannot continuously shrink the manifold beyond it.

Comment: For clarification on 3) particularly: what information do you think is derivable about a singular region from the metric, other than 'here is a point/line/etc. where the metric is singular'? I think you need to be careful about confusing 'intrinsic' singularities with coordinate singularities; e.g., the singularity at the origin of the Schwartzchild metric vs. the event horizon, which only 'blows up' because of the specific coordinates we usually use for studying it.

Comment: Indeed, and that is kind of the content of question 4: in the Schw metric, the so called Schw coordinate system has a coordinate singularity at the event horizon and a "physical" singularity at the origin, but a maximally extended analytic continuation of the metric makes the manifold regular everywhere except at that "physical" singularity. A more complicated example (to me) is the Kerr metric, where there is a ring structure to the singularity which can be made regular by analytic continuation, however the ring is still present, right?

Comment: "what information do you think is derivable about a singular region from the metric, other than 'here is a point/line/etc. where the metric is singular'?" That is why I bring up the Kerr metric with its ring singularity, which I thought was a gravitational (coordinate independent) singularity, but I learned that the ring region can be made regular by analytic extension.... The paper I quote from in question 4 directed me to the distinction such that the ring is not part of the intrinsic geometry of the singularity, and I'm wondering what that actually means and why it implies that we can...

Comment: ... only obtain information about a singularity regarding its extrinsic geometry. And I'm wondering whether a metric has to have certain properties, e.g. it can be maximally extended, etc..., in order to have sufficient condition to obtain extrinsic geometry information. I hope what I'm asking makes enough sense that an answer is possible. I edited question 3 a little to that end.

Comment: You are asking too many questions in one post. Already the first one deserves a long answer.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Oh! I didn't realize. I can split them into two questions, since the first is kind of separate from the others. But I naively thought that question 1 would be related to 2, which would be related to 3 and 4

Comment: In general, Stack Exchange discourages asking more than one question in one post. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/33671#33671

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've shortened this question, and I posted the new question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199439/intrinsic-vs-extrinsic-geometry-and-gravitational-singularities-such-as-the-ker

Comment: I'm not a GR expert, but in some sense a black hole singularity is [analogous to the vertex of a cone](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1808487), not to a topological hole. (The paper is behind a paywall unless you have institutional access, I'm afraid.)

Comment: @safesphere A very good point — it is (generally) possible to continue coordinates beyond the event horizon but it's not _just_ an artifact of the coordinate system; the trapped geodesics are a coordinate-independent, identifiable characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a geodesically complete manifold and remove a disk (make a hole) where at least one geodesic passes through, then you get a manifold with a hole which is geodesically incomplete and you have that sort of spacetime singularity.

On the other hand, a singularity of spacetime is not necessarily a hole. For instance, consider the maximal extension of Schwarzschild spacetime, which is homeomorphic to a contractible region in $R^4$.  The region $r=0$ where the singularity lies  is not topologically a hole but a spacelike hypersurface $T^2-X^2=1$. Here $T$ and $X$ are the [Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates).